# PayPal PHP SDKの使用時のエラーについて

Tags: paypal

PayPal PHP SDKの使用時にエラー「Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found (クラス’PayPal\Rest\ApiContext’が見つかりません)」が出るのはなぜですか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

このエラーは、PHP SDKのファイルパスが見つからなかったことを示しています。

この問題を解決するには、Composerを使ってベンダーフォルダーを更新してください。以下に例を示します。

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
$api = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
 new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
    $client_ID,
    $client_Secret
  )
);
$api->setConfig([
 'mode'=>'sandbox',
 'http.ConnectionTimeOut'=>30,
 'log.LogEnabled'=>false,
 'log.FileName'=>'',
 'log.LogLevel'=>'FINE',
 'validation.level'=>'log'
]);
```

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask